# What is the leading alternative to the "stages" model of grieving?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request

In "[Cautioning Health-Care Professionals: Bereaved Persons Are Misguided Through the Stages of Grief](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0030222817691870)" by Stroebe et al. the popular "5 stage model" of Kübler-Ross is incorrect. Stroebe et al. argue:

> the regularities of stage theory are too simplistic and limited; they
>   fail to represent the complex emotions and processes of grief and
>   grieving. They also lack empirical foundation. Using stages in
>   practice is potentially harmful, and yet an (perhaps the) ultimate
>   goal of theory construction in our field is to enable health-care
>   professionals to provide tangible help to those who need it.

What are the leading theories/models of bereavement and how are they superior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "[Theories of Grief and Bereavement](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46630969_Theories_of_grief_and_grieving)" by Boerner et al. (2015) the leading theories are:

- The Four Component Model from Bonanno and Kaltman

  1. Context in which loss occurs
  2. Subject meanings associated with loss
  3. Changes in representation of the lost loved ones over time
  4. Presence of coping and emotion processes
- [The Dual Process Model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47716739_The_Dual_Process_Model_of_Coping_with_Bereavement_A_Decade_on) from Stroebe and Schut

  1. Loss-oriented coping
  2. Restoration-oriented coping

The article also notes that further work needs to be done in terms of:

- Effects of inter-personal relations
- Influences of cultural background
- Biological aspects